# How to reshaping and pivot Tables in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I have raw data as following example. Variables row corresponds with range of Values; Time column corresponds with Values.
Then, I would like to arrange them in dataframe with expected output. 3 columns, Variables is principle columns and  Values and Time are the corresponding columns. But I don't know how to re-arrange.
I hope I explained clearly for you to understand my question.

```
Variables                  var1   var2   var3   var4
Time                     Values
2014-07-11 19:50:20           1      5      9     13  
2014-07-11 19:50:30           2      6     10     14 
2014-07-11 19:50:40           3      7     11     15
2014-07-11 19:50:50           4      8     12     16
```

Expected output:

```
Time                  Variables  Values
2014-07-11 19:50:20   var1       1 
2014-07-11 19:50:30   var1       2
2014-07-11 19:50:40   var1       3 
2014-07-11 19:50:50   var1       4 
2014-07-11 19:50:20   var2       5 
2014-07-11 19:50:30   var2       6
2014-07-11 19:50:40   var2       7 
2014-07-11 19:50:50   var2       8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `pd.melt` and it's fine.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.melt(df, id_vars='Time', value_vars=list(df.columns[1:]), var_name='Variables', value_name='Values')
```